# Parse XML document into individual xpaths without document foreknowledge

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

Given the following XML document:

```
<Element0 AttributeA="A">
  <Element1 AttributeB="1" AttributeC="C" AttributeD="D">
    <Element2>nodeValue</Element2>
  </Element1>
  <Element1 AttributeB="2" AttributeC="C" AttributeD="D">
    <Element2>nodeValue</Element2>
    <Element3 AttributeE="E">
        <Element4 AttributeF="F">nodeValue</Element4>
    </Element3>
  </Element1>
  .
  .
  .
  .
</Element0>
```

How do I parse (shred, de-construct, translate) the document into individual xpaths (see below) ***without*** foreknowledge of the content of the xml document?

```
//Element0[@AttributeA='A']/Element1[@AttributeB='1' and @AttributeC='C' and @AttributeD='D']/Element2
//Element0[@AttributeA='A']/Element1[@AttributeB='2' and @AttributeC='C' and @AttributeD='D']/Element2
//Element0[@AttributeA='A']/Element1[@AttributeB='2' and @AttributeC='C' and @AttributeD='D']/Element3[@AttributeE='E']/Element4[@AttributeF='F']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it. Note that I also include the position so you get a totally unique XPath for each element, even if it has the exact same attributes as one of it's siblings.

**XML Input**

```
<Element0 AttributeA="A">
    <Element1 AttributeB="1" AttributeC="C" AttributeD="D">
        <Element2>nodeValue</Element2>
    </Element1>
    <Element1 AttributeB="2" AttributeC="C" AttributeD="D">
        <Element2>nodeValue</Element2>
        <Element3 AttributeE="E">
            <Element4 AttributeF="F">nodeValue</Element4>
        </Element3>
    </Element1>
</Element0>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',local-name())"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('[',count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name()=local-name(current())])+1,']')"/>
            <xsl:if test="@*">
                <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
            <xsl:text> and </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('@',local-name(),'=&quot;',.,'&quot;')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
/Element0[1][@AttributeA="A"]
/Element0[1][@AttributeA="A"]/Element1[1][@AttributeB="1" and @AttributeC="C" and @AttributeD="D"]
/Element0[1][@AttributeA="A"]/Element1[1][@AttributeB="1" and @AttributeC="C" and @AttributeD="D"]/Element2[1]
/Element0[1][@AttributeA="A"]/Element1[2][@AttributeB="2" and @AttributeC="C" and @AttributeD="D"]
/Element0[1][@AttributeA="A"]/Element1[2][@AttributeB="2" and @AttributeC="C" and @AttributeD="D"]/Element2[1]
/Element0[1][@AttributeA="A"]/Element1[2][@AttributeB="2" and @AttributeC="C" and @AttributeD="D"]/Element3[1][@AttributeE="E"]
/Element0[1][@AttributeA="A"]/Element1[2][@AttributeB="2" and @AttributeC="C" and @AttributeD="D"]/Element3[1][@AttributeE="E"]/Element4[1][@AttributeF="F"]
```

Comment: Simple, straightforward, speedy ... and successful! Exactly what I need (including your position addition). Thanks @Daniel-Haley!

Answer (score 0):

[XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) does something very similar if you use it as `xml el -v file.xml`. It will give you path and attributes with values. However, it will not give you attributes in the middle of the path, just when that node is the tip. For your example, it produces:

```
Element0[@AttributeA='A']
Element0/Element1[@AttributeB='1' and @AttributeC='C' and @AttributeD='D']
Element0/Element1/Element2
Element0/Element1[@AttributeB='2' and @AttributeC='C' and @AttributeD='D']
Element0/Element1/Element2
Element0/Element1/Element3[@AttributeE='E']
Element0/Element1/Element3/Element4[@AttributeF='F']
```

Comment: Thank you Alexandre for your response. I've gone with Daniel's approach.